# Conditional expectation for the reciprocal of a normal

Tags: mathematical-statistics

We know the expected value of $1 \over X$, where $X$ is a normal random variable, does not exist. But suppose we condition on an interval not containing zero. For example, if $ \mu_X = 10$ and $\sigma_X = 1$, what is

$E [{1 \over X} | ( 9<X<10 )] $ ?

I know numerical integration or an approximation can be used, but can an analytic formula be found? If so, what technique is used to evaluate the integral?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "analytic formula." The expectation is an [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: I have managed to get to versions similar to the exponential integral, but nothing that matches the definition. For example, I get an exponent of $-t^2$ on $e$ rather than an exponent of $-t$. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Sorry: you get the Ei only when $\mu_X=0$.

Answer (score 3):

I will post an answer to a simpler case based on whuber's comment. If $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and we know $Z > a > 0,$  then the formula for for the conditional expectation of $1 \over Z$ is
$$E[{1 \over Z }| Z > a ] = {{E_1(a^2/2)} \over {{2^{3/2}\sqrt \pi}}  (1-\Phi(a))} \ ,$$  where $E_1(x)$ is defined in the link found in the first comment.

It's not too hard to take it one step further and determine the expression when $Z$ is constrained to an interval, where again $a > 0.$ Here is what I found: $$E [{ 1 \over Z } | a < Z < b ] = { {E_1(a^2/2)}-{E_1(b^2/2)} \over {2^{3/2}  \sqrt \pi} \ [\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]} \ .$$

And, continuing in this vein, let $Y \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $d \gt c \gt 0.$ Then this further generalizes to $$E [{ 1 \over Y } | c < Y < d ] = { {E_1(c^2/2\sigma^2)}-{E_1(d^2/2\sigma^2)} \over {2^{3/2}  \sqrt \pi} \ [\Phi(d/\sigma)-\Phi(c/\sigma)]} \ .$$